# MySql Event is not working

Tags: mysql

I have got this mysql data structure

```
 | create_t   | delete_t   |
 | 1479643496 | 1479643616 |
 | 1479643496 | 1479643616 |
 | 1479643637 | 1479643757 |
```

`create_t` and `delete_t` are both BigInt
And i have created an event like this

```
CREATE EVENT assaassas
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 50 SECOND
    DO
DELETE FROM Test WHERE delete_time<='$date->getTimestamp()'"
```

But it is fruitless.

Comment: What is the relationship between `create_t`, `delete_t`, and the table `Test` ?

Comment: there are both in `Test` @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: The `WHERE` clause is either right or it's not.  So, is it logically correct?

Comment: @Murad Murader - Have you enable the Scheduler **SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;** or enabled it in the my.cnf

Comment: @BerndBuffen i am testing this on cPanel

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no it is not correct.Because 1479643757 is less than $date->getTimestamp()

Comment: @BerndBuffen i checked and it is Off is there way to make it ON on shared hosting

Comment: @Murad Murader - If event_scheduler has been set to Disabled, you cannot change the value at runtime. Changing the value of the event_scheduler variable requires the SUPER privilege.

Comment: @BerndBuffen yes i know.thanks!